# PHP SQL - Update query to update only if new information is not null

Tags: php, mysqli

I am able to fully update my SQL using PHP.
No connection issues and no errors, so I'm not posting that info.

I simply need help on specifying my update query to not change the column if the new info is `NULL`.

```
 $sql4 = "update `Tickets` SET `newowner` ='".$_POST["ownernew"]."' where 
 `referencenumber` ='".$_POST["newref"]."'";
```

I will give some context

- `newowner` = the owner of a ticket in my ticketing system ( the column)
- `ownernew` = is the field in which my update query pulls from
- `referencenumber` = is the column for the unique ticket number, so it knows which row to update , by pulling it from the `newref` textbox

I currently have a select box , with the ID of `ownernew`.

However, it has a default selection set, which has no value - so its currently sending nothing to the server and wiping out the current owner.

I want it, so if nothing is selected it doesn't update that one column.

I'm sure that I have to put if `null` query in there, but I don't know where and how it should go in?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [**your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: we need to know what the schema and values are.

Answer (score -1):

Dont do the Query if you Data not correct

```
if($_POST["ownernew"] != null) {
    //do sql query
}
```